# JQuery Selector div > 2nd div > 3rd li

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="component-content login-wrap2">
<div class="login"></div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <a href="/shipzilla/login?view=registration">
            Not a member yet?
            <span>Sign up now!</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change the attribute for the href in the 3rd li.
The problem, what selector should I use so that I could user the .attr() function. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Do you not have control over the HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I already have the selector.. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give u content of third li.

```
alert ($("ul li:nth-child(3)").html());​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div:eq(2) li:eq(2)').attr('href' , '/shipzilla/Cart')
```

will change the href to the new value..

You can also try these selectors..

```
$('div:eq(2) ul li:eq(2)');
    $('div:eq(2) ul li:nth-child(3)');
```

Try this code

```
$(function() {
    var elem = $('div:eq(2) li:eq(2)');
    console.log('Old href : ' + elem.attr(href));
    $('div:eq(2) li:eq(2)').attr('href', '/shipzilla/Cart');

    console.log('New href : ' + elem.attr(href));
});​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Vqgc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for selecting div > 2nd div > 3rd li . This will help you to select this .

```
console.log($("div div:nth-child(2) ul li:nth-child(3) a"));
```